# I cannot complete page 246 of Python Data Analytics. The last four lines of code always produce "Invalid Syntax"

Tags: python

I am in the process of completing an assignment in Python that requires me to copy the code in a book "starting at In[7]". However, when I attempt to do so, I am informed that the "<" in  in "invalid syntax". I have underwent numerous attempts to resolve the issue as shown below, but I always get an error of some sort. What is the correct way to write this?!

Attempt 1 and how it is supposed to look;

```
In [7]: t = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)
...: y1 = np.sin(math.pi*t)
...: y2 = np.sin(math.pi*t+math.pi/2)
...: y3 = np.sin(math.pi*t-math.pi/2)
In [8]: plt.plot(t,y1,'b*',t,y2,'g^',t,y3,'ys')
Out[8]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbd2e48>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe10b8>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe15c0>]
```

The result of attempt 1 as shown above.
[image: The result of attempt 1]

Attempt 2;

```
In [7]: t = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)
...: y1 = np.sin(math.pi*t)
...: y2 = np.sin(math.pi*t+math.pi/2)
...: y3 = np.sin(math.pi*t-math.pi/2)
In [8]: plt.plot(t,y1,'b*',t,y2,'g^',t,y3,'ys')
Out[8]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbd2e48>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe10b8>,
 <matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe15c0>]
```

The result of attempt 2 as shown above.
[image: The result of attempt 2]

Attempt 3;

```
In [7]: t = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)
...: y1 = np.sin(math.pi*t)
...: y2 = np.sin(math.pi*t+math.pi/2)
...: y3 = np.sin(math.pi*t-math.pi/2)
In [8]: plt.plot(t,y1,'b*',t,y2,'g^',t,y3,'ys')
Out[8]: [matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbd2e48,
 matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe10b8,
 matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0xcbe15c0]
```

The result of attempt 3 as shown above.
[image: The result of attempt 3]

[image: Finally, the code that I am expected to duplicate (I import pyplot, math, and numpy in a previous cell as part of the project requirements)]
Finally, the code that I am expected to duplicate (I import pyplot, math, and numpy in a previous cell as part of the project requirements)

I've looked for a solution for a long time but I can't find anything useful. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: That is an output line from the interpreter, not a part of the code.

Comment: I've tried removing them but it doesn't work either. (I didn't include the attempt because I thought it was part of the code but it didn't work anyways.)

Comment: Doesn't the error go away if you remove everything after "Out[8]"? (and maybe then add anything starting from "In[9]" if present).

Comment: Oh, you just solved it! I feel like an idiot (it doesn't help that I have no experience in Python) but thank you so much!

Comment: In most interpreters, you shouldn't be entering the `in[]:` and `...: ` line beginnings either; `t = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)`, instead of `in[1]: t = np.arange(0,2.5,0.1)` for example. While the `in[]:` and `...: ` line beginnings might not cause an error, they're adding work for no benefit